# A group without proper subgroups is a cyclic group

Tags: group-theory

If a group $G$ has no nontrival proper subgroups, prove that $G$ is a cyclic group with order $p$, where $p$ is a prime number.

Comment: Except if the group is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint :

For some non identity element $g\in G$ what can you say about group generated by $g$..

- Can $\langle g\rangle$ be a proper subgroup?